# Import meetings from google calendar ical link in react

Tags: reactjs, node.js, google-calendar-api

I have a react application with node server. I want to get the ical link(google calendar) from the user, parse and read all the events to display it on my calendar app. Please suggest me what will be the best way to acheive this requirement.